# AWS Cognito Sign Up: Error 37

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3

```
if let pool = Aws.pool {
        showLoadingView()
        let emailAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "email", value: email)
        pool.signUp(email, password: password, userAttributes: [emailAttribute], validationData: nil).continueWith { task in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideLoadingView()
                if let error = task.error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    self.displayAlert(message: "error_alert".localized)
                } else if let user = task.result?.user {
                    Session.shared.newUser = Session.NewUser(awsUser: user, email: email, password: password, mobileNumber: mobileNumber)
                    if let confirmed = task.result?.userConfirmed,
                        confirmed != NSNumber(value: AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed.rawValue) {
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(AuthenticationViewController.instance(), animated: true)
                    } else {
                        Aws.login(navigationController: self.navigationController!, email: email, password: password)
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Error message from AWS:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain error 37.)

When I log in with the same identity pool, there is not an error. What is the issue here, and why is there no information anywhere about error 37?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code that you are seeing corresponds with [AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorUsernameExists](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/a50e487cc71fc9345bdd55b8bdfe0eb08c7250ac/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/CognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h#L62).

It is the numeric value of the enum that you see in the reference link.
Are you trying to sign-up a username that already exists?

Comment: Apparently I was. Thank you. What good is `error.localizedDescription` if I need to decode each potential error in order to provide my own localized descriptions?